# I need some explanation about some syntax

Tags: javascript, function, dom-events

I have seen this kind of code in one of Google's google maps documentation. My question is about the listener. Instead of the callback function passed immediately after the 'click' action the `showArrays()` function is called but not passed nothing as parameter. On the other hand `showArrays()` function uses event as parameter. Please explain me this kind of calling the function.

```
element.addListener('click', showArrays);
  //some code here
}


 function showArrays(event) {
  // some code here
 }
```

Comment: The browser supplies the event parameter when it invokes the event handler.

Comment: That first `}` a syntax error in the context of the provided snippet.  Also it should be `addEventListener`

Comment: You should understand that JavaScript is a Functional language. Functions are data and can be passed around as arguments, just as strings, Booleans, and numbers can be. That's what's happening here. The callback isn't being called, it's being referenced so that it can be called later.

Answer (score 0):

Think of the names of functions as variables themselves. `showArrays` is a variable, that, when given an event, does something with it.

You can pass the functions name as a parameter to addListener so that it can call the callback when the element is clicked on. It's important to note that you are not calling the function in the first line, only passing a reference to that function.

You can show this property in the browser's console with this test:

```js
function test() { console.log("Test was called"); }
```

Notice if you say `var x = test` nothing is printed to the console. But if you say `var x = test()` you see the print. Finally, if you do `var x = test; x()` you will see the print out, because you called the test function after assigning it a new name.

Answer (score 0):

Notice that in the `element.addListener('click', showArrays)` line, showArrays does NOT have brackets after it. That means it's not being called. Instead, the entire function is being passed as a parameter to the addListener method.

Event listeners in JS will take the handler function you provide when you attach them with addListener (or addEventListener, more commonly), and, when the event occurs, they will call that function and pass an event object to it.

In other words, showArrays is not being called until the element is clicked, and all event listeners inherently get passed an event object at that point, detailing the specific properties of the event.

Answer (score 0):

One of the syntax cases for describing a function is:

```
var showArrays = function (event) {
  // of the code here
}
```

and it is precisely this argument value that the addEventListener method uses, and even other functions such as setTimeout or setInterval, among others.

Answer (score 0):

addEventListener method always sends the "event" object as an argument to the callback function. When you use the anonymous function, it is obvious to see it:

```
element.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    // some code here
});
```

But when you send to the addEventListener method a link to the function you want to be called when the event occures (in your case it is a link to showArrays function), addEventListener sends "event" object as an argument to this function just on itself. So, although it's not obvious to see it, but the "event" object is being sent to showArrays function automatically.

```
element.addEventListener('click', showArrays); // the event object will be sent automatically
```

And you will have an access to the "event" object inside the showArrays function. But, of corse, in showArrays function declaration you should have a parameter for catching the "event" object.

```
function showArrays() {} // it's not going to work
function showArrays(event) {} // it will work
```